# New RAM is not recognized by OS but shown in BIOS

Tags: linux, memory, bios

I got new RAM for my computer. I previously checked specifically that I buy the modules as before. Now my System only recognizes 1 of the 3 new modules.

I checked withfree -g and only got 16 GB instead of the now new 32 GB. But with dmidecode --type 17 I can see that the computer sees all modules but does not use it or does not include it in the OS. Also in the BIOs, it recognizes all 4 modules and shows 32GB of available RAM.

I use Linux Mint Tara and Windows 10 on the computer and both detect only 16GB of ram.

Additional hardware information:

```
mainboard: AX370-Gaming 3-CF (the firmware was already updated to make it compatible with Ryzen 2nd Gen)

processor: Ryzen 7 2700X
```

Does someone have an idea how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello. Can you post the output of the following command on Linux: `cat /sys/devices/system/memory/*/state `? Edit it in your question.

Comment: ~$ cat /sys/devices/system/memory/*/state
online
online
online
[...] it continues like this until the end. It's 128x "online".

Comment: Tried the memtest program, how much does it see & test? \

Comment: memtest says that I have just 16 GB of total Memory but if I view the deteiled information it shows me all 4 modules with 8 GB each.